# How to accomodate different arguments for entity class

Tags: android, kotlin, constructor, entity

I am calling my entity class in an `if/else-if` statement for 2 different conditions and the values I pass into the parameters depend on the condition.  In the `if` block, I am passing 3 parameters and in the `else-if` block, I am passing 4.  The entity's object is throwing an error because it is expecting 4 parameters.  I want the first parameter to be optional and I'd like to know if there is a way to do that in Kotlin.

This is my entity class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "entry_table")
data class Entry(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) 
    var id: Int? = null, 

    val username: String? = null, 
    val hint: String? = null, 
    val password: String? = null)
```

And this is the `if/else-if` block where I'm inserting values into the entity object:

```
if (requestCode == ADD_ENTRY_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            ...

            val entry = Entry(username, hint, password)
            ...

        } else if (requestCode == EDIT_ENTRY_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            ...

            val entry = Entry(id, username, hint, password)
            ...

        }
```

In Java, you could solve this problem by creating 2 constructors with matching number of parameters but I wonder if we can do the same in Kotlin or if there is a different approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try moving the id to the end, like so:

```
@Entity(tableName = "entry_table")
data class Entry(
    val username: String? = null, 
    val hint: String? = null, 
    val password: String? = null,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) 
    var id: Int? = null)
```

And then creating it like:

```
val entry = Entry(username, hint, password, id)
```

Or, if you want to keep the id as the first parameter, you can use named arguments like this:

```
val entry = Entry(username = username, hint = hint, password = password)
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can and probably should use multiple constructors.

The downside with your approach is that all the properties must be optional for technical reasons. But I guess, `username` and `password` actually are mandatory. The consequences are loss of compile time checks (and therefore prone to NPEs) and cumbersome reading (`!!` needed when accessing username).

You can avoid these problems following this approach:

1. To make your class have the default no-arg constructor, that is required by JPA, use the compiler plugin https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#jpa-support
2. Make mandatory properties non-nullable (I assume, only `hint` is optional)
3. Use as many secondary constructors as you like

---

```
@Entity(tableName = "entry_table")
data class Entry(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) 
    val id: Int, 

    val username: String,
    val hint: String?, 
    val password: String
) {
    constructor(
        username: String,
        hint: String = null,
        password: String = "change it"
    ) : this(0, username, hint, password)
}
```

In a more realistic scenario, only `id` and `username` were immutable. `password` and `hint` should be allowed to change.

```
@Entity(tableName = "entry_table")
data class Entry(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) 
    val id: Int, 
    val username: String
) {
    constructor(
        username: String,
    ) : this(0, username)

    var hint: String? = null
    var password: String = "change it"
}
```